# Handling unget and putback with file streams

Tags: c++, c, c++11, stream, locale

I have implemented `std::basic_streambuf` derived wrapper around `std::basic_filebuf` which converts between encodings. Within this wrapper I use a single buffer for both input and output. The buffering technique comes from [this](http://www.angelikalanger.com/IOStreams/Excerpt/excerpt.htm) article.

Now, the problem I can't figure out is this. My internal buffer is filled on calls to `underflow`. According to the article, when switching from input to output, the buffer should be put in a state of limbo. To do this, I need to `unget` the unread data in the buffer. Reading the docs and the source codes, `unget` and `putback` are not guaranteed to succeed. This will leave me with an invalid `tellg` pointer with the next input operation.

I'm not asking for somebody to write this for me, but I am asking advice as to how to manage ungetting data from `std::basic_filebuf` in a way that will not fail.

I think, the only sure way is to calculate the bytes that would be written to file and adjust the offset accordingly. It's not as simple as it sounds though. The `filebuf` may have an associated `locale`, unknown at compile time. I tried getting the facet and passing the data through it's `out` member, but it doesn't work. The previously read data may have a non default `mbstate_t` value, and some `codecvt` objects also write a BOM.

Basically, it's almost impossible to calculate the 'on file' length of a section of file data after it has passed through a `codecvt`.

I have tagged this question with 'c' since 'c'-file streams also work with buffers and also use get and put pointers. `std::basic_filebuf` is just a wrapper around a 'c'-file stream. Answers in 'c' are also applicable to this problem.

Does anybody have any suggestions as to how to implement unlimited unget on file streams?

Comment: IMHO you either do your encoding and fully control the codecvt, or rely on the existing unknown codecvt to do the encoding. Otherwise you get your bytes encoded twice.

Comment: @n.m. Not possible in this case. There are just too many locales to take into account. My code must work on an existing `basic_filebuf` with any `locale` loaded into it.

Comment: If you have no control over `codecvt`, you have no control whatsoever over actual bytes written to the file. This means you cannot perform any encoding yourself.

Comment: Please remove the `c` tag as this is clearly a C++ question.

Comment: @haneefmubarak This is not limited to c++. c also buffers input/output and also handles putpack/unget. Any answer in either c or c++ is a valid solution.

Comment: In that case, in C, assuming that you simply wanted to put back the same data, instead of modifying the file stream, you could simply seek to a position 1 byte behind: `fseek(pFile, ftell(pFile) - 1L, SEEK_SET);`. Have a look at stdio.h: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/

Comment: @haneefmubarak It's not as easy as you make out. What if the encoding is UTF-8 or worse Shift-J? Seeking back becomes a whole lot more complicated. I solved the problem by keeping a cache of encoding states at fixed offsets then seeking forward from one of those.